# Windows HTTP issue

Tags: windows, http

I use HTTP protocol for send binary data to server (PUT request and Content-Type: application/octet-stream). Until recently time this worked fine.
But now I getting 504 http error on Windows (I try it on several Windows mashines).

I try do all what imagine, so correct this behavior. When I catch request through Fiddler. I see what full request  has sended to server, but server not respond.

I send absolutly same request from Linux machine, so it still works fine as a before.

In addition I notice, what Windows mashine works correctly (PUT request and Content-Type: application/octet-stream)  when in the body request contains only literal characters.

Any idea, what I do with this? Is it known issue?

Comment: Add some samples of requests that worked and not worked.

Comment: I get this [request](ftp://ftp.asu.ru/incoming/kav/KavWks%206.0.4.1424/requests.saz) through Fiddler.

Comment: This is a working request or a non working one ? please give a working request too if this is non working !

Comment: The above file contains a both requests. If you open it in Fiddler you see the first request, which returns 204 (it success) status result, and the second, which returns 504 (it failure) status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this issue. Problem wasn't on Windows.
This has came with server kernel version (kernel 3.0.23).
When I update kernel (Ubuntu server from 3.0.23 to 3.0.24 version), it was working again.

That most likely problem in recognizing TCP packages.